# Allocate memory when retrieving 28,000 records data using nusoap_client in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7, soap-client, nusoap

I want to retrieve 28,000 records data from an external API, but when I execute a function to do this, I get an error like this:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException:   
 Out of memory (allocated 780140544) (tried to allocate 27262984 bytes)
```

My function:

```php
public function get_all_data(){
   $url = "http://xxx.xx.x.xx/services/DS_Get_Pending?wsdl";
   $client = new \nusoap_client($url, 'wsdl');

   $pDate = isset($_GET["pDate"]) ? $_GET["pDate"] : '26/02/2017 01:01:01';
   $operation = 'getPending';
   $param1 = array(
         'pDate' => $pDate,
   );
   $result = $client->call($operation, $param1);

   print_r($result);
   exit();
}
```

What's the best way to allocate memory for retrieving 28,000 records pf data?

Comment: Please add your code. If you are trying to store 28,000 records with a lot of data the error makes sense. What do you need to do with the data? You should be able to iterate over it and not exceed the limit if you release it.